# Why the java Class object has a different API/Signatures when accessing it as a Class variable than through a .getClass() method?

Tags: java, lang

I see that the Class instance has a different signature, at least regarding the `getAnnotation` method, comparing the Class object and a `<some-object>.getClass()` object.

The following code shows an example case.

```
@Bar("hello")
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Foo foo=new Foo();
        Bar bar1,bar2,bar3;

        Class clazz=foo.getClass();

        //This compiles and work (as expected)
        bar1=foo.getClass().getAnnotation(Bar.class);

        //This does not compile!
        bar2=clazz.getAnnotation(Bar.class);

        //This one copiles and work!
        bar3=(Bar) clazz.getAnnotation(Bar.class);

    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Bar {
    String value();
}
```

Note: this whole example is copy&paste from my editor.

--------MODIFICATION TO BETTER SHOW THE SCENARIO

I forgot to show in the example that the "code" is not aware of the existence of Foo, like an external Library:

```
class SomeExternalLibrary{
    public static void someMethod(Class clazz){        
        Bar bar2,bar3;        

        bar2=clazz.getAnnotation(Bar.class);        

        //This one copiles and work!
        bar3=(Bar) clazz.getAnnotation(Bar.class);
    }
}
```

The code that uses this external library would be something like this:

```
SomeExternalLibrary.someMethod(Foo.class);
```

Sorry for not been so aware of my scenario reality :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Looking at all your answers makes me realize that there is more context that I have not properly shown in the example. In the example I didn't show that the "code" does not has any knowledge about Foo existence, like an external library. Here is a more specific snipped showing the scenario. (I'm editing the original question)

Comment: Good question! It's not obvious why you can't use a generic method on a raw type, where the parameter of the type and the parameter of the method are not related. It just seems to be that way.

Answer (score 3):

This question is about Generics.

The reason for the compilation error is that you don't include the class information in the `clazz` variable.

Changing your code to this will solve the problem:

```
Class<Foo> clazz = foo.getClass();
```

Comment: That's the correct solution, but it doesn't really explain why you can't call a generic method on a raw Class instance, as the type parameter of Class and the type parameter of getAnnotation are not related.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question to reflect an extension of my concern. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is right in that it has to do with generics, but the code change should be:

```
Class<? extends Foo> clazz = foo.getClass();
```

---

In your second scenario the same thing is going on. Since you are not using generics the `getAnnotation(Bar.class)` just returns an `Annotation`. If you were to use generics like below it would work :

```
public static <T> void someMethod(Class<T> clazz) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question to reflect an extension of my concern. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

getAnnotation is defined using generics as

```
<T> T getAnnotation(Class<T> clazz)
```

which means that no typecast is needed for the annotation provided that generics can be resolved at compile time.  In the second example, the `Class clazz` variable has been stored as a raw type.  If you were to qualify that as `Class<? extends Foo> clazz` the second example would work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question to reflect an extension of my concern. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it works if you use:

```
Class<?> clazz
```

instead of

```
Class clazz
```